# sendmail: rewrite part of envelope sender address

Tags: smtp, sendmail, aix

I'm is configuring `sendmail` on aix server and I need to rewrite part of envelope sender address.

```
from this: user@servername.foo.org
to this: user_it@foo.com
```

As you can see what I need is rewrite part of the user name adding `"_it"` and change `servername.foo.org` to `foo.com`.

I was trying to add some rules in "envelope sender rewriting" part but doesn't work. 
This are the rules:

```
#envelope sender rewriting

SEnvFromSMTP

R$-      $@ $1_it@foo.com

R$-@$w   $@ $1_it@foo.com

R$-@$+   $@ $1_it@foo.com

R$+      $@ $1_it@foo.com
```

Extra information.
Aix 7.1
Sendmail version 8.14.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail rules get the email address in quite different (rewritten) form.
In your case use the command below too see it:

```
#!/bin/sh
sendmail -bt << END
/tryflags es
/try esmtp user@servername.foo.org
END
```